# Domain model for education

Tags: design, domain-model

Are there any domain models already created for education industry? For example we have [Prima IBCS](http://www.prima-solutions.com/frontOffice/en/products/primaIBCS.jsp) for insurance. I was looking for something along similar lines.

Comment: data specification != domain model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A instructor at San Jose State University has a [partial example](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/ooa/analysis/DomainModeling.htm) of a domain model for education. There's the [National Education Data Model](http://nces.ed.gov/forum/datamodel/Information/aboutThe.aspx) that covers similar ground. The now defunct ["E-Len" Project](http://www2.tisip.no/E-LEN/) might be of use. Some more focus in regards to what problem you are trying to solve would be useful to better answer your question. The resources listed are links from the first two pages of a Google search.